# Is there a way to find out how close you are to the Epic and Legendary badges?

Tags: support, badges

Is there a way to find out how close you are to the Epic and Legendary badges, that is how many times you've hit the daily limit? I've seen clever things done with queries so I'm guess there is a way to calculate this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Head to https://physics.stackexchange.com/reputation for your reputation stats.  Near the bottom you'll see something like:

> days represented 197
>
> rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 3 days
>
> earned at least 200 reputation on 4 days
>
> earned 250 reputation from suggested edits

It's not clear to me if the "upvotes only" number is used or if the potentially larger 200 rep number is used.

Comment: The badge description doesn't say anything about upvotes only, so I think it counts total reputation for the day.

Comment: Thanks, that's the info I needed.

Answer (score 4):

The one-stop shop for tracking your badge progress (not that you should really be doing that) is [this answer to Badge Progress Reports on the mother meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/badge-progress-reports/143653#143653). There are  usually a few relevant queries in the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) to choose from.

In this particular case, I can't find one that looks reliable; the mother meta thread points to [the reputation page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/reputation) that Brandon pointed out.

If you're feeling competitive, though, [Legendary Badge advancement TopCount](http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/160805/legendary-badge-advancement-topcount) will show the leaderboard: the number of days users have reached the daily cap, from über-legendary to mortarboard. [Top users by the number of times they earned 200/day](http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/129639/top-users-by-the-number-of-times-they-earned-200-day)
 does the same, though there's a slight discrepancy with the first one.

If you're wondering exactly what the criterion is, [this answer by Nick Craver](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/88526), and his comments below it, confirms that you only need 200 reputation total in [one day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/42184/) to add a count towards these badges.

Comment: Thanks Emilio :-)

Comment: No problem. To be honest, that list should be seen in log scale, thanks to you and Luboš.